# Preventing hibernate from row duplication by column value

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, primary-key, unique-constraint

I have app which is storing parsed urls inside MySQL db and populating parsed sentences, then parsed Words etc. using cascade (so I just save url, db insert rest automatically).

In the ProcessedUrl POJO I have fields:

```
Long id
String url
Date date
Set<Sentence> sentences
```

For now PK is id which is generated in native way. I want to achieve something like that - when user enter some url which is already parsed and stored into db, it won't be parsed again/duplicated.

What is suitable way of achieving this using `hbm.xml` mapping?

EDIT:

ProcessedUrl POJO:

```
public class ProcessedUrl {

    private long id;
    private String url;
    private Date date;
    private Set<Sentence> sentences;

    public ProcessedUrl() {
    }

    public ProcessedUrl(String url, Date date) {
        this.setUrl(url);
        this.setDate(date);
    }
    public ProcessedUrl(String url, Date date, Set<Sentence> sentences) {
        this.setUrl(url);
        this.setDate(date);
        this.setSentences(sentences);
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public Set<Sentence> getSentences() {
        return this.sentences;
    }

    public void setSentences(Set<Sentence> sentences) {
        this.sentences = sentences;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if(this == obj) return true;
        if(!(obj instanceof ProcessedUrl)) return false;

        ProcessedUrl that = (ProcessedUrl) obj;
        EqualsBuilder eb = new EqualsBuilder();
        eb.append(this.getUrl(), that.getUrl());
        return eb.isEquals();
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        HashCodeBuilder hcb = new HashCodeBuilder();
        hcb.append(url);
        return hcb.toHashCode();
        }   

}
```

ProcessedUrl.hbm.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping package="model">

    <class name="ProcessedUrl">
        <id name="id">
                <column name="url_id" />
                <generator class="native"/>
        </id>
        <property name="url" type="text"/>
        <property name="date" type="java.util.Date" />

        <set name="sentences" cascade="all" >
            <key column="PROCESSED_URL_ID" />   
            <one-to-many class="model.Sentence" />
        </set>               
    </class>  
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: post complete code for ProcessedUrl POJO and current hbm xml file ?

Comment: @javaguy Here you are.

Answer (score 0):

> When user enters some url, which is already parsed and stored into db,
>   it won't be parsed again/duplicated. What is suitable way of achieving
>   this using hbm.xml mapping ?

You can't do this with simple hbm mappings because the previously parsed URL is already stored in the database and you need to validate that the latest received URL value already exists in the database.

So, to achieve this, you need to follow the below steps:

(1) Get the URL from App (DO NOT PARSE HERE)

(2) Check the URL already exists in database

(3) If URL does NOT exist, PARSE THE URL NOW and save to database

(4) If URL already exists, log an warning/error or ignore the request